# ActionEvent in Java

Tags: java, swing, events, action

I recently started learning Java and i came across a statement including `(ActionEvent e )`.
What does `e` mean and is it a standard? Or can we use anything else in place of `e`? Because when I change this by any other variable, it still works.

Is `e` an instance of `ActionEvent`?

Comment: You should read the swing tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ to get to a level where you can ask real questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a parameter, so you can replace it with any letter or word you want. It's so common though, since most of the automatically generated actionevents would generate the parameter 'e'.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting that the comments that describe 'e' as variable are upvoted more.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `e` is just the name of the variable. Use whatever you want for the name. `e` is just commonly used because `event` starts with `e`.

Answer (score 3):

`e` is a reference to an instance of ActionEvent.

It is a variable, read more about Java variables here.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html